# Using agent name as a condition for a selectOutput in AnyLogic

Tags: simulation, anylogic, event-simulation

I have a simulation that has two agent types. Applicants and Priority Applicants. (Priority Applicants are created by splitting Applicants.) There are two Services, Normal Issuance and Priority Issuance. I need to direct agents to the counters based on the agent type.

[image: SelectOutput]

I have tried using below code in SelectOutput condition. In "If condition is true", I have used the condition,

```
agent InstanceOf Applicant
```

But this is giving me 3 errors.

[image: error messages]

Is there a way to fix those errors? Or is there any other way to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of InstanceOf with Capital I and O, use instanceof (only lowercase)

I don't know if that solves the errors you have, but that's at least 1 of the errors you need to solve.

Comment: It did. I used the suggestion from Anylogic earlier. Now it's working.

Comment: make sure to use code-complete when writing code (press Ctrl+Space) and these problems will not happen :-)